# SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I have a problem when try to deploy my app to the hosting via gem Capistrano. With authorization via SSH-keys everything is ok.
I have next error:

```
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as hosting_yurta24@calcium.locum.ru: scp: /tmp/yurta24/git-ssh.sh: Permission denied
scp: /tmp/yurta24/git-ssh.sh: Permission denied
```

My deploy.rb file is:

```
lock '3.4.0'

require 'net/ssh/proxy/http'

sshproxy = Net::SSH::Proxy::HTTP.new('x.x.x.x', 8080)
set :ssh_options, { :proxy => sshproxy }

    application = 'yurta24'
    login = 'yurta24'
    $user = 'hosting_' + login
    $server = 'calcium.locum.ru'
    rvm_ruby_string = '2.1.5p273'
    deploy_to = "/home/#{ $user }/projects/#{ application }"
    unicorn_conf = "/etc/unicorn/#{ application }.#{ login }.rb"
    unicorn_pid = "/var/run/unicorn/#{ $user }/#{ application }.#{ login }.pid"
    unicorn_start_cmd = "(cd #{ deploy_to }/current; rvm use #{ rvm_ruby_string } do bundle exec unicorn_rails -Dc #{ unicorn_conf })"

    set :application, application 
    set :repo_url, "https://github.com/verrom/yurta24.git"
    set :deploy_to, deploy_to
    set :pty, true
    set :default_env, { path: "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin" }

  namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
    end
  end
end
```

My production.rb file is:

```
connect_to = "#{$user}@#{$server}"
role :app, [connect_to]
role :web, [connect_to]
role :db,  [connect_to]
set :enable_ssl, true
```

Full error list is:

```
verevkinra@ubuntu:~/apps/yurta24$ cap production deploy:check
DEBUG [b5b4061f] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/.rvm ] as hosting_yurta24@calcium.locum.ru
DEBUG [b5b4061f] Command: [ -d ~/.rvm ]
DEBUG [b5b4061f] Finished in 1.346 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [8c816727] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d /usr/local/rvm ] as hosting_yurta24@calcium.locum.ru
DEBUG [8c816727] Command: [ -d /usr/local/rvm ]
DEBUG [8c816727] Finished in 0.180 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [a427409d] Running /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm version as hosting_yurta24@calcium.locum.ru
DEBUG [a427409d] Command: ( PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm version )
DEBUG [a427409d]    rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
DEBUG [a427409d] Finished in 0.468 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
DEBUG [205f64d3] Running /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm current as hosting_yurta24@calcium.locum.ru
DEBUG [205f64d3] Command: ( PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm current )
DEBUG [205f64d3]    system
DEBUG [205f64d3] Finished in 0.399 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
system
DEBUG [730c9a49] Running /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do ruby --version as hosting_yurta24@calcium.locum.ru
DEBUG [730c9a49] Command: ( PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do ruby --version )
DEBUG [730c9a49]    ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
DEBUG [730c9a49] Finished in 0.613 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
INFO [4c8c1c1b] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/yurta24/ as hosting_yurta24@calcium.locum.ru
DEBUG [4c8c1c1b] Command: ( PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/yurta24/ )
INFO [4c8c1c1b] Finished in 0.173 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG Uploading /tmp/yurta24/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as hosting_yurta24@calcium.locum.ru: scp: /tmp/yurta24/git-ssh.sh: Permission denied

scp: /tmp/yurta24/git-ssh.sh: Permission denied
```

My Gemfile is:

```
 gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
  gem 'unicorn'
```

Second error list is:

```
rake aborted!
Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`:
Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"]
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:110:in `database_configuration'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:117:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:315:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/releases/20151020084626/config/initializers/dragonfly.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/releases/20151020084626/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"]
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:110:in `database_configuration'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:117:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:315:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/releases/20151020084626/config/initializers/dragonfly.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/releases/20151020084626/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as hosting_yurta24@calcium.locum.ru: rake exit status: 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a link to your project, so I can see your capfile and unicorn configs

Comment: @moeabdol https://github.com/verrom/yurta24.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a permission problem, it could be one of many things; however, make sure your user "hosting_yurta24" owns the /tmp directory

```
$ sudo chown hosting_yurta24 /tmp
```

This could be because when you'v created this user you didn't assign it administrative privileges.

Regarding your second issue, capistrano is reporting back that you don't have a `database.yml` file on your VPS. I presume also you don't have `secrets.yml`. Here is how you create them:

First make sure you have these two directories. If you don't have them already, create them:

```
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/config
/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/log
```

The first directory will hold your project and database configurations. The second directory is essential for your application to save its logs. They both must be there!

Now! cd into `/home/hosting_yurta24/projects/yurta24/shared/config` and create two files

```
database.yml
secrets.yml
```

In database.yml paste the following:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql                # if your using postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  database: yurta24_production       # database name
  username: postgres                 # database username
  password: password                 # database password
  host: localhost
```

Go back to your local machine, into your rails project directory and from the terminal type in:

```
rake secret
```

The terminal should dump a long mixture of strings and numbers. This is your application secret. Copy it and then on you VPS secrets.yml:

```
production:
  secret_key_base: apsifq193uq8djf1jqe8er18jee9jd8eqeh8fqe8fqehh8qehfq    # paste your secret here
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thats helped! But I'm again have an error from previous question :) I've add error list to this question. Could you look on it?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the appropriate user rights to that `/tmp` folder would not work.

However, changing the temporary path worked. Add this to your `deploy.rb`:

```
set :tmp_dir, "/home/deploy"
```